# highlighting the new drawn number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to specify my page and add that only the latest generated number is highlighted. The current page highlights each number and I would like it to highlight only the latest number in the table and then go out, i.e. when the number 12 is drawn, the cell with the number 12 will be highlighted, and if the number is drawn 55 then 12 goes out and 55 lights up

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var bingo = {
      selectedNumbers: [],
      generateRandom: function () {
        var min = 1; //Liczba początkowa
        var max = 89; //Liczba końcowa
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        return random;
      },
      generateNextRandom: function () {
        if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
          alert("Koniec");
          return 0;
        }
        var random = bingo.generateRandom();
        while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
          random = bingo.generateRandom();
        }
        bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
        return random;
      },
    };
    $("td").each(function () {
      var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
      $(this)
        .addClass("cell" + numberString)
        .text(numberString);
      $(".cell" + numberString).attr("CellValue", numberString);
    });
    $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
      var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
      $(".bigNumberDisplay span").text(random);
      $("td.cell" + random).addClass("selected");
      $("td").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("CellValue") === random) {
          $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        }
      });
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var returnString = "Are you sure?";
      if (e) {
        e.returnValue = returnString;
      }
      return returnString;
    };
  });
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <title> Bingo</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" value="Wylosuj numer stolika" />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="numbersTable">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <br />

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.bigNumberDisplay {
  font-size: 6em;
}

.numbersTable {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #999;
}

td {
  min-width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}

td.selected {
  color: #000000;
}
```

[a basic design in which each number highlights](https://jsfiddle.net/c3qefu2d/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: Instead of setting the inline style `background-color: yellow`, add a class to the newly appended cell. When the generate button is clicked, remove this class from all cells and add it only to the newly appended cell.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var bingo = {
    selectedNumbers: [],
    generateRandom: function() {
      var min = 1; //Liczba początkowa
      var max = 89; //Liczba końcowa
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      return random;
    },
    generateNextRandom: function() {
      if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
        alert("Koniec");
        return 0;
      }
      var random = bingo.generateRandom();
      while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
        random = bingo.generateRandom();
      }
      bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
      return random;
    },
  };
  $("td").each(function() {
    var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
    $(this)
      .addClass("cell" + numberString)
      .text(numberString);
    $(".cell" + numberString).attr("CellValue", numberString);
  });
  $("#btnGenerate").click(function() {
    var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
    $(".bigNumberDisplay span").text(random);
    $("td.cell" + random).addClass("selected");
    $("td.active").removeClass("active");
    $("td").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("CellValue") === random) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
    });
  });
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var returnString = "Are you sure?";
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = returnString;
    }
    return returnString;
  };
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:yellow;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.bigNumberDisplay {
  font-size: 6em;
}

.numbersTable {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #999;
}

td {
  min-width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}

td.selected {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <title> Bingo</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" value="Wylosuj numer stolika" />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="numbersTable">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <br />

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CSS class to make the highlighted number yellow:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I would add that class to the cell that you want to highlight. It looks like you are looping through all `td` elements and finding the one with the right `CellValue` attribute. You can select that element using CSS selectors instead.

So try replacing this code:

```
$("td").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("CellValue") === random) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
});
```

With:

```
$('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
$('td[CellValue="' + random + '"]').addClass('highlight');
```

This would also remove the `highlight` class from the cell you first selected.

This is using CSS attribute selectors to target the correct cell. You can read more about CSS attribute selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great. I just thought it would be fun to make a concise version of this with [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) and [jquery](https://jquery.com/).

```js
var ROWS = 10;
var COLS = 9;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var htmlToAdd = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    htmlToAdd += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < COLS; j++) htmlToAdd += "<td style=\"width:" + 100 / COLS + "%;\">" + (i + (COLS + 1) * j) + "</td>";
    htmlToAdd += "</tr>";
  }
  $("table").html(htmlToAdd);
});

function showNext() {
  $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
  if (pick = rando($("td").not(".shown")).value || false) $("#result").text(pick.addClass("shown").addClass("highlighted").text());
}
```

```css
body{ padding:50px; text-align:center; }

#result{ font-size:96px; }

table{ border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; }

td{ color:transparent; border:1px solid #999; text-align:center; font-size:25px; }

td.shown{ color:black; }

td.highlighted{ background:yellow; }

button{ margin:20px 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>

<div id="result">0</div>
<button onclick="showNext();">Show next</button>
<table></table>
```